# adMob mediation adding a network

Tags: android, ios, admob

In AdMob's mediation section, you have the option of adding an ad network. Depending on the network, then you have to type in some credentials, such a a key, or login etc. Is this all that you have to do? If the ad network is listed in admob does that mean that you will start receiving ads, or do you have to download an SDK and add custom code for each? I understand that 'custom events' are used for networks that aren't listed, but does that mean that the networks that are listed work out of the box so to speak? The documentation is pretty bad.

Comment: Did you read: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/mediation

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the SDK for that network and an adapter between Admob and that network (NB the adapter is often contained within the network's library).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, documentation is bad. As well as the standard admob code, you also need to include an adapter for another network in your app code in order to get that other network to work. If your submitted app doesn't have the adapter in the code and you try to put that network in the mediation stack, then your app won't crash, it just won't show ads from that network.

The adapters and the instructions for including them can be found here https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/mediation-networks